# Validate Excel file is downloaded in Selenium Web driver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm able to download excel file by clicking Download button which comes under DOM ,
after that i want verify downloaded file is same one.
AUTO IT is not allowed in project.
I have tried below code for verification on local but if i will push this code to repo.
then user path will get change and code will fail.

```
`String filepath = "C:User\\Dhananjay\\Downloads";


String fileName = "report.xlsx"

File targetFile = new File(fileName,filePath);

if(! targetFile.exists())'
{

system.out.println("File is verified")`
}else{
system.out.println("file not downloaded")
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`String userProfile = System.getProperty("user.home");` returns `%USERPROFILE%` variable.

So you can use `String filepath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads";`

Works even on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for solution Sir, tried this  but it's not verifying , it's passing for wrong filename also.

Comment: targetFile is wrong, should be `File targetFile = new File(fileName + filePath);` or `File targetFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\" + fileName);` Use debug to see variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have found way to validate on local path and it's generic one

File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") +\\Downloads);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

boolean found = false;

File f = null;
 


for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {

 if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
      String fileName = listOfFile.getName();
       System.out.println("File " + listOfFile.getName());
       if (fileName.matches("5MB.zip")) {
           f = new File(fileName);
           found = true;
            }
        }
    }
Assert.assertTrue("Downloaded document is not found",found );

f.deleteOnExit();
```